# Is the retag privilege gone?

Tags: bug, tags, edits

Why does [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17429391/revisions) require approval (and gives me 2 reps) while [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17370649/revisions) didn't? Is the retag privilege gone?